Interactive Keyboard Dismiss does not work
I have a very basic view where the keyboard is overlayed on the view to create a blurry background. When I move the keyboard from the Vstack to overlay the view, the bug in the video below happens where the textfield does not move with the keyboard, and instead stays in the middle of the screen until the keyboard fully disappears.
google drive video
struct InteractiveTopKeyboard: View {
   @State var text = ""
   @State private var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0
   @State private var isKeyboardVisible = false
   private let keyboardWillShow = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)
   private let keyboardWillHide = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)
   
   var body: some View {
       NavigationStack {
           VStack {
               ScrollView {
                   LazyVStack {
                       ForEach(0..<20, id: \.self) { _ in
                           RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
                               .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                               .frame(height: 300)
                               .rotationEffect(.degrees(180.0))
                               .scaleEffect(x: -1, y: 1, anchor: .center)
                       }
                   }
               }
               .rotationEffect(.degrees(180.0))
               .scaleEffect(x: -1, y: 1, anchor: .center)
               .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.interactively)
               .padding(.bottom, keyboardHeight)
               .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.3), value: keyboardHeight)
           }
           .ignoresSafeArea()
           .onAppear {
               addKeyboardObservers()
           }
           .onDisappear {
               removeKeyboardObservers()
           }
           .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
               HStack {
                   Spacer()
                   TextField("Enter text", text: $text)
                       .padding(.horizontal)
                       .padding(.vertical, 8)
                       .background(.gray)
                       .clipShape(Capsule())
                   Spacer()
               }
               .padding(.top, 5)
               .padding(.bottom, 30)
               .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
           }
       }
   }
   
   private func addKeyboardObservers() {
       keyboardWillShow
           .merge(with: keyboardWillHide)
           .sink { notification in
               if let keyboardFrame = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect {
                   withAnimation {
                       isKeyboardVisible = notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification
                       keyboardHeight = isKeyboardVisible ? keyboardFrame.height : 0
                   }
               }
           }
           .store(in: &cancellables)
   }
   
   private func removeKeyboardObservers() {
       cancellables.removeAll()
   }
   
   @State private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
}


What do you mean by moving 'the keyboard from the Vstack to overlay the view'?  Because I ran your code in both the simulator and on a device and didn't see the bug in the video.

@clawesome when I have the textfield inside the LazyVstack (right below the ForEach) the interactive scroll dismiss works right and the textfield moves with the keyboard. But when I put the textfield in the overlay, it gets stuck in the middle of the screen and doesn't move with the keyboard. I ran this on a sim and a real device and it happens on both. Im running iOS 17.7.
